# How to create multiple rows combining data sets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have three tables and i need an out put which has data from two tables, i would like to create the same using macro.

Table A

```
A
B
C
D
```

Table B

```
Apple
Orange
Pears
```

Table C

```
Americas
Asia
Europe
```

The Output i need is

```
A Apple Americas
A Apple Asia
A Apple Europe
A Orange Americas
A Orange Asia
A Orange Europe
```

So i guess for each letter from Table A, there would be 12 additional rows created. The above is the sample data and I have around 5000 rows in Table A.

Comment: Hi Raystafarian, i generally use MS Access and create three different tables and then just create a query which would provide the required output. However, we no more have access to MS Access. Hence struggling to find a way out.

Comment: I have another question, in case in Table C i have data as mentioned below, with two columns
Table C
Americas USD
Asia JPY
Europe EUR

And the Output would be something like this
A Apple Americas USD
A Apple Asia JYP
A Apple Europe EUR
A Orange Americas USD
A Orange Asia JPY
A Orange Europe EUR

How to go about in this case. Sorry, I guess should have pointed out in the first instance itself.

Comment: just offset the write location and the read location. So you could do `cells(i,3) = e.value` AND `cells(i,4) = e.offset(0,1).value`

Comment: Hi Ray, Again with an issue, this time, the query runs but creates only till 32,727 rows, but i am expecting that my data would have around 150,000 rows. I error i get is run time error 6

Based on some web research i made "Dim i As Long" and run the query but no help.

Comment: What version excel are you using? And what line gets highlighted with the overflow?

Comment: Hi Ray, I again ran the query today morning making the "Dim I As Long" and it worked fine. Thanks.

Also, i am currently trying to build a macro and i might end up requesting help from you..so if you can share me ur email id, i can reach out to you in future. If only if you are willing to though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, just modify as appropriate

```
Sub Umesh()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range

i = 1

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
If c <> "" Then

    For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
    If d <> "" Then

        For Each e In Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A:A")
            If e <> "" Then

            Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(i, 1) = c.Value
            Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(i, 2) = d.Value
            Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, 3) = e.Value
            i = i + 1

            End If
        Next e

    End If
    Next d

End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Raystafarian. The code is working fine. Very helpful.